# confused on how to use the pow() function to negativley power something?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm not sure if I have the pow function in the right place, but I can't figure out how to set months to -months powered.

Here is the original formula i am suppose to base this off of: 
**principal*(rate/12)/(1 - (1 + rate/12)^-months)**

I am getting the error message: 
**error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments**

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int y = -1;
    double months;
    double principle = 1000;
    double rate = 7.20;
    double monthly_pay;

    cout << "Please enter the number of months you have to pay back the loan:";
    cin >> months;
    monthly_pay = principle*(rate/12)/((1-pow((1+rate/12), -months)));
    cout << monthly_pay << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look carefully at `(1-(1+rate/12)pow(months, y)`. Does `pow()` take two arguments? Even if it does, is this expression syntactically correct?

Comment: No it didnt look right and i couldnt figure it out. Thats why i asked publicly because i was unsure and didnt understand online examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double pow (double base, double exponent);
      //Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument.
```

so change

```
monthly_pay = principle*(rate/12)/(1-(1+rate/12)pow(months, y);
```

to

```
monthly_pay = principle*(rate/12)/((1-pow((1+rate/12), -months));
```

Comment: wow thank you so much, that solved my issue. I can now add my loop and what not. Thanks again for the great solid and quick response!

Comment: When i input 12 for months it gives me a 602 dollar monthly payment for 1000 dollar loan. Doesn't seem right to me. **Because i did not divide my rate by 100 to get my percent** doh..

Comment: All I've done is translate the equation you presented into a code version. If there's a logic problem behind this equation, then I'm not sure :p

Answer (score 0):

I broke your algorithm into smaller functions (I hope you don't mind). I came up with this code that compiled just fine for me. I believe you have the concept understood, you just forgot to multiply the pow(a,b) function using the asterisk.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int y = -1;
double months;
double principle = 1000;
double rate = 7.20;
double monthly_pay;
double a, b;


cout << "Please enter the number of months you have to pay back the loan:";

cin >> months;

a = rate / 12;
b = pow(months, y);

monthly_pay = (principle * a) / (1 - (1 + a) * b);


cout << monthly_pay << endl;


return 0;
```

}

I hope this helps!